# Is the concept of “grace” present in Hinduism?

Tags: karma

The importance of Karma and its consequences is well known,by which things that happen to an individual can be attributed to his past karma.

(Even in the famous hymn “Enna thavam..” the hymn‘a answer lies in the story of how a couple pleased Lord Brahma ,who granted them the boon to be parents of Gof,later reborn as Nandalal and Maa Yashoda.)

My question is,can anything good(or for that matter bad),happen to a person,simply because the Parabrahm decides it to be,out of grace on the person,and not because the person had done corresponding karma?

Comment: Short answer no. Also, how can something bad happening to a person be called `grace`?

Comment: Yes there is 'grace' in Hindusim

Comment: @kesarling Maybe as a form of test,to develop the person’s Bhakti.(?)

Comment: Everything happens by the grace of Ishwar. However, all physical phenomeno follow the laws of karma. So when Narad had attack of kaam, it was due to his pride of tapasya, which he did on recommendation of Ishwar. This in turn had many consequences for both narad and many others including Vishnu.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a correct idea about grace.

It is parabrahman who chooses the person who will attain moksha. Divine grace is absolutely necessary for moksha.

> This Atman cannot be attained by the study of the Vedas, or by
> intelligence, or by much hearing of sacred books. **It is attained by
> him alone whom It chooses.** To such a one Atman reveals Its own form.

**Katha Upanishad I.ii.23**

Let me now answer your specific question.

**Can anything good(or for that matter bad),happen to a person, simply because the Parabrahm decides it to be, out of grace on the person,and not because the person had done corresponding karma?**

Parabrahman dispenses grace only for moksha. It is one's karma that decides whether you will have good and bad experience in the world . Parabrahman does not normally interfere in the working of the world.

Comment: But with regards to moksha,it is evident that the Parabrahm becomes graceful to such a person ,after he has struggled/put effort in this goal,right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.